# What is the idiomatic way to create and use Enumerations in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-composer

[Found some evidence here that enum was supported in Ballerina](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ballerina-dev/Cl0ZPoQ-THg) at one point, but [it seems to have been removed](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/4016). Is anyone aware of a recommended/supported/idiomatic way to deal with enumerated values in Ballerina?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we had removed the enum type from the language a while ago. Now you can generically define enumerated values using constants and the union type.

```
// Following declarations declare a set of compile-time constants. 
// I used the int value for this example. You could even do const SUN = "sun". 
const SUN = 0;
const MON = 1;
const TUE = 2;
const WED = 3;
const THU = 4;
const FRI = 5;
const SAT = 6;

// This defines a new type called "Weekday"
type Weekday SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT;

function play() {
    Weekday wd1 = WED;
    Weekday wd2 = 6;

    // This is a compile-time error, since the possible values 
    //  which are compatible with the type "Weekday" type are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6
    Weekday wd3 = 8;
}
```

---

Let me explain how this works according to the language specification. Consider the following type definition. You can assign possible integer values as well as boolean values (`true` or `false`) to a variable of type `IntOrBoolean`.

```
type IntOrBoolean int | boolean;
IntOrBoolean v1 = 1;
IntOrBoolean v2 = false;
```

Likewise, you can define a new type definition which contains only a few values such as this. Here `0` denotes a singleton type which has value `0` and `1` denotes another singleton type which has the value `1`. Singleton type is a type which has only one value in its value set.

```
type ZeroOrOne 0 | 1;
```

With this understanding, we can rewrite our `Weekday` type as follows.

```
type Weekday 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5| 6;
```

When you define a compile-time constant such as `const SUN = 0`, the type of the variable `SUN` is not `int`, but a singleton type with the value `0`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit awkward, but will have to do.

Comment: I understand. Ballerina doesn't have a straightforward way to define enumerated values.